# Don't know how to make a True variable into False

Tags: python

I'm new-ish to python and know how to make a False variable True, but cant make a True variable False.

Comment: `variable = False`

Comment: `var = False`  Where are you stuck?

Comment: Show us how you make a False variable True, and how you've tried to make a True variable False, and we'll help correct your code.

Comment: this can be solved with a google search and is out of place on stack overflow please read the [mcve guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: simply redefine the variable.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't a stupid question - we all begin somewhere.  You should be able to change the status of a variable at any time by simply calling the variable and making it equal to the status you want.  For example:

```
variable = True
```

or

```
variable = False
```

If the variable is already in that state, making it equal to that state will not change it.  You can then use other statements, like "if" to do things based on the state of the variable.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but questions like this get a lot of hate because they show very little effort in *communicating the problem*.

Comment: Idk what i did wrong the first time, or if i made a mistake but its working now, thank you...

Comment: @hyp3dog: That's why we expect, that you show the code and the error message in your question.